# how to use setter and getter from html page in ionic 2

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I am in the need to set a value (variable) and get change after performing some specific task.
I would like to share my system environment, which is as below-

```
******************************************************
Your system information:

Cordova CLI: 6.4.0 
Ionic Framework Version: 2.0.0-beta.10
Ionic CLI Version: 2.1.8
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.1.4
ios-deploy version: Not installed
ios-sim version: 5.0.8 
OS: OS X Yosemite
Node Version: v6.2.2
Xcode version: Xcode 7.2 Build version 7C68
******************************************************
```

I wanted to use setter and getter to get this task done, see what i did-
mypage.ts-

```
import {NavController, NavParams, Content} from 'ionic-angular';
export class ListPage {
  constructor(private navCtrl: NavController, navParams: NavParams) {
    this.counter = 0;
  }
  public counter;

  getCounter(){
    return this.counter;
  }

  setCounter(count) {
    this.counter = count;
    // console.log(this.counter);
  }
}
```

and this is html template as-

```
<div *ngIf= "( getCounter()== '0')">
   .....
     ...  
      ..
     ...
   .....
</div>
<div (click)= (setCounter(getCounter()+1))
</div>
 some= line of codes
    ....
    ....
    ....
on bottom
<div ( setCounter(0))>
</div>
```

I am able to ***get the value*** which is 0, but don't know how to set it.
I want to ***set value*** without *(click)* even i have used click but i don't know how to do *without click*.

here are list of source URL which I have seen-

1. [How i can get input value within ionic 2 in my Component?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38426201/how-i-can-get-input-value-within-ionic-2-in-my-component)
2. [Angular 2 call a function/method when an event is emitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38356676/angular-2-call-a-function-method-when-an-event-is-emitted)
3. [How to call another components function in angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37587732/how-to-call-another-components-function-in-angular2)
   List 2 was a little bit useful but can't help me out.

**Hope for help**

Comment: for what event you want to increment counter?

Comment: I wanted to increment automatically, without any (click) event, don't know which directive event will work...

Comment: you mean a timer?

Comment: when do you want to increment?

Comment: Yes @raj I want increment. &&   suraj I don't want to do with timer, but with the execution flow.

Comment: I have added an answer which I think what you are lloking for. If not You need to explain when you want to increase the counter.

Answer (score 1):

See the link
[get and set in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12827266/get-and-set-in-typescript)

```
get Counter(){
    return this.counter;
  }
```

In HTML

```
<div *ngIf="Counter== '0'">
<div (click)= "setCounter(Counter+1)>"
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort @habeeb, very first- you have used wrong closing of quotes, so it's not going to work {.<div (click)= "setCounter(Counter+1)>"  ==> .<div (click)= "setCounter(Counter+1)"> }. 2. if you read carefully- I have mentioned that i don't want to to it on click.

Answer (score 0):

This example below will increase the `counter` each time  the page is visited. `ionViewDidEnter` will be called each time page is viewed. Hope this is what you are lloking for.

```
export class ListPage {
  constructor(private navCtrl: NavController, navParams: NavParams) {
    this.counter = 0;
  }
  public counter;

  ionViewDidEnter(){
    this.setCounter(this.getCounter() + 1 ) ;
  }

  getCounter(){
    return this.counter;
  }

  setCounter(count) {
    this.counter = count;
    // console.log(this.counter);
  }
}
```

Comment: Right! but @raj I am in the need to do this from .html page not from .ts,   something like <div (click)= (setCounter(getCounter()+1)) but without click event.